# DateDif based on criteria

Tags: excel, datediff

I have data that look like this:

[image]

I'd like, based on ID to get the DateDif in days of Initials and any other reassessments (Annuals and Semiannuals). Column D shows what I'd like to see while column E has notes on which cells the DateDif should work on.

I don't know where to start with this..do I use DateDif or Ifs or?
Thank you for reviewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for D4 is wrong, it should be 289

Starting in D2

```
=IF(A2<>A1,"",C2-VLOOKUP(A2,A:C,3,0))
```

If A <> the value above it then it is nothing otherwise take the value in C and minus the initial value for that ID (Done using VLookup and 0 at the end will give an exact match)

Comment: This worked beautifully. I still get 287 though. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, I didn't see it was a year later, I entered it as 2013 when testing :)

Comment: @WixLove - See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: I knew I'd do a "don't" on this forum sooner or later. I thought I had read all the do's and never read anything about this. Also, I tried to put in my table but couldn't figure out the block code or how to indent it properly so it was not due to my lack of consideration. I humbly post every time and try to be as clear as possible, grateful that a volunteer will help me. Thank you for letting me know. I'm still not sure how to put in a table properly but I'll cross that bridge when I get there again--which I'm sure will be soon!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to retrieve the correct *minuend* and *subtrahend* of the subtraction formula.

[image: DATEDIFF staggered]

The formula in D2 is,

```
=IF(B2="initial", "", C2-INDEX(C$1:C1, MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:1)*(B$1:B1="initial"), , ))))
```

Fill down as necessary.

The formula looks to column A for the last occurrence of the  word *'Initial'* according to the row it is currently on and subtracts the date from that row from the date in the current  row.

Comment: This worked also! However, I tried the other first and had already accepted--sorry I can't also give you credit.... I've moved this up as useful. Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: No worries @WixLove. This was proposed as an alternate non-numeric solution. A numerical evaluation is always preferred whenever possible.